# Cannot figure out how to write custom type

Tags: ruby, puppet

Updated:

I am trying to teach myself how to write Puppet custom types.  I have looked at this documentation: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/custom_types.html and https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/provider_development.html

Here is my contrived attempt to create a custom type that simple takes an array of strings and writes them to the file '/tmp/track-titles.txt'.

Here is my type code (modules/hello_world/lib/puppet/type/track_titles.rb):

```
# blah blah blah
Puppet::Type.newtype(:track_titles) do
  @doc = "Create track title file."

  ensurable

  newparam(:name) do
    desc "Mandaorty paramteter name ."
  end
  newproperty(:tracks) do
    desc "an arrary of strings"
  end

end
```

Here is my provider code: (modules/hello_world/lib/puppet/provider/track_titles.rb)

```
Puppet::Type.type(:track_titles).provide(:foo) do
    desc "contrived example."

    def create
        filename = @resource[:name]
        tracks.each do |t|
            system ( "echo #{t} >> #{filename}" )
        end
    end

    def destroy
        File.unlink(@resource[:name])
    end

    def exists?
        File.exists?(@resource[:name]))
    end
end
```

Here is my puppet module that uses the above: (modules/hello_world/manifests/init.pp)

```
class hello_world (
        $msg = 'Hello World',
        $track_titles = ['one','two','three'],
) {
#       notify { $msg: }
        track_titles { '/tmp/track-titles.txt':
                tracks => $track_titles,
        }
}
```

I execute this code like so:

```
$ puppet apply \
> --modulepath=/home/red/PUPPET/modules \
> --hiera_config=/home/red/PUPPET/hiera.yaml \
> -e 'include hello_world'
```

And this is the output I get:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for localhost in environment production in 0.06 seconds
Error: /Stage[main]/Hello_world/Track_titles[/tmp/track-titles.txt]: Could not evaluate: No ability to determine if track_titles exists
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.82 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong.  Also there are part of the provider code I don't get like:

```
Puppet::Type.type(:track_titles).provide(:ruby) do
```

What is this .provide(:ruby) all about?

Please help :)

Comment: You probably don't want ruby to be your provider for that type. Also, I don't think `@resource[:name]` is going to resolve correctly in your provider code. To learn what providers are conceptually, check out Peter's great answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781030/how-does-puppet-send-commands-to-the-os/41790421#41790421. Also, check this out: http://garylarizza.com/blog/2013/11/25/fun-with-providers/. Note Gary's article is for Puppet 3, but still relevant.

Comment: Type attributes that correspond to aspects of the persistent, managed state of resources are *properties*, not parameters.  It looks like `track_titles` is supposed to fall in this category.

Comment: Thanks John.  I am using 'newproperty' now instead of 'newparam' but I am getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here what I was doing wrong. For one I didn't read the documentation (https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/custom_types.html#properties-and-parameters) close enough.  It says:

Provider files should be located at `lib/puppet/provider/<TYPE NAME>/<PROVIDER NAME>.rb`

Knowing this helped figure out what the `.provide(:thing)` meant. `:thing` and `<PROVIDER NAME>` are the same thing and need to match.  So here is my updated working code:

Here is the Puppet class:

```
$ cat modules/hello_world/manifests/init.pp
class hello_world (
        $track_titles = ['one','two','three'],
) {
        track_titles { '/tmp/track-titles.txt':
                tracks => $track_titles,
                ensure => present,
        }
}
```

Here is the Type definition:

```
$ cat modules/hello_world/lib/puppet/type/track_titles.rb
# blah blah blah
Puppet::Type.newtype(:track_titles) do
  @doc = "Create track title file."

  ensurable

  newparam(:name) do
    desc "Mandaorty paramteter name ."
  end
  newparam(:tracks) do
    desc "an arrary of strings"
  end
end
```

Here is the provider code. ***This was the code I was putting the file in the WRONG directory and that is why I was getting the*** `Could not evaluate: No ability to determine if track_titles exists` ***error.***

```
$ cat modules/hello_world/lib/puppet/provider/track_titles/track_titles.rb
Puppet::Type.type(:track_titles).provide(:track_titles) do
    desc "Contrived example"

    def create
        filename = @resource[:name]
        tracks = @resource[:tracks]
        tracks.each do |t|
            system ( "echo #{t} >> #{filename}" )
        end
    end

    def destroy
        File.unlink(@resource[:name])
    end

    def exists?
        File.exists?(@resource[:name])
    end
end
```

Now here is a successful execution:

```
$ puppet apply \
> --modulepath=/home/red/PUPPET/modules \
> --hiera_config=/home/red/PUPPET/hiera.yaml \
> -e 'include hello_world'

Notice: Compiled catalog for localhost in environment production in 0.07 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Hello_world/Track_titles[/tmp/track-titles.txt]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.85 seconds

$ cat /tmp/track-titles.txt
one
two
three
```