# Puppet repository for Installing package

Tags: repository, puppet, provider

I would like to know from where does a package gets installed in Puppet when we write  a manifest in Puppet for a package resource with below attribute.
ensure => installed,

I'm aware that there are providers in puppet which send the request to software installation tools on following path(/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/provider/package ) like yum, pip, gem, apt, etc which are responsible to get this done. However, i would like to know from which repository are these packages installed. Eg. like we configure a local yum repository when we want to install packages on the server via yum command.

Is it over the internet or the puppet nodes should be configured & connected to a local repository ? OR By default Puppet comes with pre-configured repositories for these software installation tools.

I would Appreciate a good explanation in this regards. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This will be super helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781030/how-does-puppet-send-commands-to-the-os/41790421#41790421

Answer (score 0):

If the puppet nodes should be connected to the internet or not is a question that you need to answer yourself in terms of how you would like your architecture to look like. Puppet only runs package install commands that should also work if you run it yourself in the shell, such as - `yum install x` , it doesn't matter if its over the internet or not.
It would work either way, and it depends on your repository configuration.

For example, yum repository configuration is under- /etc/yum.repos.d/*
You can see in the files there where it would go look for the packages you are trying to install